# Travel restrictions or quarantine regulations due to Covid19 (machine readable, if possible)

Tags: data-request, medical, government, covid19, travel

I'm looking for datasets (or webpages) from one or many countries that lists travel restrictions and quarantine requirements for travelers entering the country.

For example, lists that countries publish to indicate for which countries travelers are required to enter quarantine upon their arrival.

Answer (score 1):

EUROPE

- **Switzerland**, html (not machine readable): https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/empfehlungen-fuer-reisende/quarantaene-einreisende.html
- **Germany**, html (not machine readable): https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html
- **France**, html (very not machine readable): https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky to find up to date data/ infos concerning the travel restrictions. Best place to look for infos is the health ministry website of the country in question. For example:

- **Tunisia** : offers [a pdf list updated continuously with 3 categories, each with each set of restrictions](https://covid-19.tn/blog/%d8%aa%d8%b5%d9%86%d9%8a%d9%81-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%af%d9%88%d9%84-%d8%ad%d8%b3%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%b9%d9%8a%d8%a9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%88%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%8a%d9%94%d9%8a%d8%a9-23-%d8%b3%d8%a8/).
- **UK** : publishes an [up-to-date list of exempted countries](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors) (from self-isolation). The webpage includes links to restrictions in **Wales**, **Scotland**, and **Northern Ireland**.

Furthermore, the following websites include some summaries of the travel status for some countries:

- [Countries Reopening Their Borders For Tourism: The Complete List](https://www.traveloffpath.com/countries-reopening-their-borders-for-tourism-the-complete-list/)
- https://reopen.europa.eu/en, not up-to-date but includes some historical data.
- [covid-19 entry requirements by country easy travelers guide](https://www.traveloffpath.com/covid-19-entry-requirements-by-country-easy-travelers-guide/)
- [Travel restrictions by country](https://www.kayak.com/travel-restrictions)